# Labels as Values in Inline Assembly Macros

Tags: c, assembly, x86, arm, inline-assembly

I'm wondering how I can load a register with a the value of a label in inline assembly.

I tried naively doing it in this fashion:

```
#define inline_macro(a) \
    asm volatile("1: movw %[rega], #:lower16:1b\n" \
                 "   movt %[rega], #:upper16:1b\n" \
                 : [rega] "+r" (a)       \
                 :                       \
                 :                       \
    );

int main(void){
    register int   i     asm("r2");
    register void* value asm("r1");
    i++;
    i += 2;
    inline_macro(value);
    return i;
}
```

However, the object dump shows this assembly code being generated:

```
00000000 <main>:
   0:   e52db004    push    {fp}        ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
   4:   e28db000    add fp, sp, #0
   8:   e1a03002    mov r3, r2
   c:   e2833001    add r3, r3, #1
  10:   e1a02003    mov r2, r3
  14:   e1a03002    mov r3, r2
  18:   e2833002    add r3, r3, #2
  1c:   e1a02003    mov r2, r3

00000020 <.L11>:
  20:   e3001000    movw    r1, #0
  24:   e3401000    movt    r1, #0
  28:   e1a03002    mov r3, r2
  2c:   e1a00003    mov r0, r3
  30:   e24bd000    sub sp, fp, #0
  34:   e49db004    pop {fp}        ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
  38:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

What I want is for the value 0x20 to be loaded into register r1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a whole instruction for getting the address of a label into a register: [`ADR`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0802b/Babcjaii.html).

Since it works by arithmetic on the PC, it's completely position-independent and doesn't have unlimited range, but neither seems an issue here - taking advantage of the assembler's "current instruction" pseudo-label `.`, the example in the question becomes:

```
#define inline_macro(a) \
    asm volatile("adr %[rega], . \n"     \
                 : [rega] "=r" (a)       \
                 :                       \
                 :                       \
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know arm asm, but you're trying to get the address of the `movw` instruction?  Does ARM really require two separate 16bit `mov` instructions for that?

It looks like you're disassembling the `.o`, where the linker hasn't replaced symbol references with their actual values, and you're seeing `0` as a placeholder.

Since I think your code doesn't depend on the old value of the register, you should use it as a write-only output operand (`=r`), not a read-write operand (`+r`).

Comment: `ldr r0, =label` would work too, unless the literal pool is too distant. Move instructions don't have enough bits to load a 32-bit value into a register. I also notice that replacing 1b with any other string compiles too, so I'm thinking that my syntax is a bit off. I suspect that the inline assembly cannot find the label 1b and just defaults to 0.

Comment: @squirem: did you miss my 2nd paragraph?  Try linking, not just assembling.  Thanks for the clue about ARM asm.  I'm so used to x86 I didn't even think about the difficulties of a 32bit immediate in a fixed-insn-length ISA.

Comment: @squirem If the assembler couldn't find the label, it would complain loudly and fail. As Peter implies, the _assembler_ doesn't know what the absolute address will be, so it encodes 0 and emits a relocation in the object for the linker to fix up later - note how the assembler's had to generate a real label (`.L11`) in place of its local one. Try `objdump -r` to see the missing piece of the puzzle ;)